# ubuntu 13.04 social lens not working?

Tags: 13.04, twitter, social

I'm not getting any results in the social lens. I have a couple of twitter accounts set up in online accounts and they seem to work ok in the friends-app but still nothing appears in the social lens. Any help with finding the cause would be good.

Comment: Same here, no results in social lens..

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem until I found out that "Search online sources" was not enabled in Unity Tweak Tool (Unity => Launcher => Search). After enabling it, it worked immediately.

Answer (score 0):

Unity Tweak tool does the trick as suggested. Just to clarify it's the "Search online sources" that needs to be turned on. That's Unity > Search > Search online sources.